# Move/Resize Child Browser View based on Parent

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to create an application in electron whereby I load a child browser window in a specified location.
When the parent moves or gets resized I would like the child to update its position and size relative to the parent.
Note, in MacOS this seems to be done automatically via the parent/child relationship.

I have added some code to listen for the bounding box of the div element but that is not the actual position relative to the screen, i.e. it doesnt support multiple co-ordinate spaces (monitors).

Is there anyway to embed browserwindow within another or make it update based on the location of a div from the application?

On the image below, the white rectangle is what I want the child browser window to overlay

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I feel stupid!  Use BrowserView instead of BrowserWindow and set the view (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-view)

Comment: do u know how it make it behave like `webview`/`flex`, so that it fills up the remaining space of the window?

Answer (score 0):

Not the brightest idea but you can create a DOM representative with an empty div for location and size calculation and update BrowserView on Window resize